# Skip NA in data.table by

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to use `data.table` but would like skip the calculation of the `j` part if the `by` corresponds to missing (`NA`):

Here is an example data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(y=10, g=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA))
```

It looks like this

```
> DT
     y  g
 1: 10  1
 2: 10  1
 3: 10  1
 4: 10  2
 5: 10  2
 6: 10  2
 7: 10  2
 8: 10  2
 9: 10 NA
10: 10 NA
```

Now I'd like to do the `by=` on `g` and the two rows 9 and 10 will be lumped together because they have the same value `NA`.

```
> DT[,.N, by=g]
    g N
1:  1 3
2:  2 5
3: NA 2
```

I'd like to keep the `NA` line in the output but would want to skip the calculate part in the result, ie., get the output, where `N` is empty when `g` is `NA`

```
> DT[,.N, by=g]
    g N
1:  1 3
2:  2 5
3: NA NA
```

I thought I could access the value of `g` through `.GRP` but that only gives the group index and not the value. Is it possible to make the calculation conditional on the missing status of the `by` variable?

Comment: The _value_ of your grouping variable _can_ be accessed in `j` - it has length one if used in `j` (see [FAQ 2.10 Inside each group, why are the group variables length-1?](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#inside-each-group-why-are-the-group-variables-length-1). So something like `DT[ , if(!is.na(g)) .(n = .N) else NA_integer_, by = g]` would work.

Comment: What's wrong with filtering by `!is.na(g)` in the `i` argument? I.e `DT[!is.na(g),.N, by=g]`

Comment: @ScottRitchie I think that would remove the `NA` line from the result. I still want it for subsequent joining.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [data.table do not compute NA groups in by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366830/data-table-do-not-compute-na-groups-in-by)

Comment: @scmi There might be duplicates but your linked question is *not*. The OP clearly states *I'd like to keep the NA line in the output* while in your linked question the `NA` group should be skipped at all.

Comment: @scmi How can my question be a duplicate when it was asked and answered several months before the question you refer to? Oh and as Uwe mentions I want to keep the `NA`s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this one:

```
DT[, .N * NA^is.na(g), by = g]
```

> ```
>     g V1
> 1:  1  3
> 2:  2  5
> 3: NA NA
> ```

It is an algebraic version of [Henrik's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444012/skip-na-in-data-table-by#comment81844070_47444012) `if ... else ...` clause. 
It uses the fact that `NA^0` returns `1` while `NA^1` returns `NA` and that `FALSE`  and `TRUE` can be coerced to `0` and `1`, resp.

If you want to control the column name:

```
DT[, .(n = .N * NA^is.na(g)), by = g]
```

> ```
>     g  n
> 1:  1  3
> 2:  2  5
> 3: NA NA
> ```

Alternatively, if above appears to tricky you can resort to data.table chaining (thanks to Sotos for bringing this up):

```
DT[, .N, by = g][is.na(g), N := NA][]
```

This will change the value of `N` after aggregation.

Comment: I suspect [Frank's answer to the near-duplicate data.table do not compute NA groups in by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366830/data-table-do-not-compute-na-groups-in-by/49366998#comment86879373_49366998) is faster and clearer