# data.table do not compute NA groups in by

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, grouping, na

This question has a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444012/skip-na-in-data-table-by) but the question is too specific and I'm not able to apply it to my own problem.

I would like to skip a potentially heavy computation of the NA group when using `by`.

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(X = sample(10), 
                Y = sample(10), 
                g1 = sample(letters[1:2], 10, TRUE),
                g2 = sample(letters[1:2], 10, TRUE))

set(DT, 1L, 3L, NA)
set(DT, 1L, 4L, NA)
set(DT, 6L, 3L, NA)
set(DT, 6L, 4L, NA)

DT[, mean(X*Y), by = .(g1,g2)]
```

Here we can see there are up to 5 groups including the `(NA, NA)` group. Considering that (i) the group is useless (ii) the groups can be very big and  (iii) the actual computation is more complex than `mean(X*Y)` can I skip the group in an efficient way? I mean, without creating a copy of the remaining table. Indeed the following works.

```
DT2 = data.table:::na.omit.data.table(DT, cols = c("g1", "g2"))
DT2[, mean(X*Y), by = .(g1,g2)]
```

Comment: [Near-duplicate for single-variable 'by' case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444012/skip-na-in-data-table-by)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an `if` clause:

```
DT[, if (!anyNA(.BY)) mean(X*Y), by = .(g1,g2)]

   g1 g2       V1
1:  b  a 25.75000
2:  a  b 24.00000
3:  b  b 35.33333
```

From the `?.BY` help:

> `.BY` is a `list` containing a length 1 vector for each item in `by`. This can be useful [...] to branch with `if()` depending on the value of a group variable.

Comment: I think it would be nice to have syntax like `DT[, mean(X*Y), by=.(g1,g2), having=!anyNA(.BY)]`, requested here  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788

Comment: I was about to post `DT[rowSums(is.na(DT[, .(g1,g2)])) == 0, mean(X*Y), by = .(g1,g2)]`, but this is much faster.

Comment: @Frank I tried but couldn't understand the role of .BY here. Please help me understand.

Comment: @Manish You can try `DT[, {print(.BY); cat("next group...\n")}, by=.(g1, g2)]` to get intuition for what it is. If that doesn't clear it up, I've invited you to a chat room to follow up

Comment: Works fine thank you. Considering that `data.table` recycle the memory allocated for the biggest group I guess this does no change anything in the memory allocation. It just skips the computation. Fair enough :-)

Comment: That's quite brilliant, it should be documented more widely in recipes and cheat-sheets.

Comment: @smci Thanks :) Fwiw, here's my cheat sheet including `.BY` http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#notation-cheat-sheet though not the `j = if (...) ...`